# ListView grouping and selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView bound to a collection of objects. Depending on the choice of the user, objects are grouped by their properties.

Example, I have the basic collection of fruits (variety, amount, origin) :

```
Banana, 10, Africa
Apple, 2, France
Pear, 30, France
Banana, 40, Africa
```

Becomes, grouped by variety of fruits :

```
Banana
    Banana, 10, Africa
    Banana, 40, Africa

Apple
    Apple, 2, France

Pear
    Pear, 30, France
```

For each object and group header, I add in XAML a checkbox for selection. With the checkbox in the group header, I would like to select the entire group. 
For the example above, if I check the header "Banana", the 2 rows below in the same group are checked.

This is the XAML for my ListView :

```
<ListView Name="MyCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
  <ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Name="SelectAllGroup" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ListView.GroupStyle>

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Sélection" >
       <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
       </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn>
     <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="N°" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Numero}"/>
     <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Nom" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Nom}" />
     <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Responsable" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Responsable}" />
     <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Détail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Detail}" />
     <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Calibre" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Calibre}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this by putting a Command onto the Checkbox in the header
then in the command method something like this:

```
private void UpdateSelectedFruitGroup()
{
    MyFruitCollection.Where(f => f.Variety == "Banana").ForEach(f => f.IsSelected = true);
}
```

in order to do the ForEach you'll need to put this Extension into a static class:

```
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");

        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        foreach (var e in enumerable)
        {
            action(e);
        }
    }
```

basically it just goes through each item in a collection and performs an action on it. In this case it sets the IsSelected property.

Comment: but how do I know that the checkbox in the header is "Banana" or anything else ?

Comment: i guess it depends how you've set up your groups, when i did this you had to select the group before you could toggle the checkbox, so all i had to do was change "Banana" to the selected group.

Comment: well ... don't know why but I can't select any groups. In my ListView, I can select items, but not the group